# Creating and accessing a private folder on my server

Tags: php

i want to be able to make a folder where users upload content too, and then an admin can use a password possibly to view the folder and make choices on to approve or reject the content.  best way to do this?

Comment: Please stop writing tags in titles.

Answer (score 2):

A secure and easy way is to do it with .htaccess and .htpassword to allow only specific people to access the directory.

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you link me maybe to more info on how it works?  ive been reading about it but dont quite understand how it works to fit my problem

Comment: This link should be useful: http://www.addedbytes.com/lab/password-protect-a-directory-with-htaccess/ Or try any other Google search like "protect directory Apache htaccess"

Comment: This is an easy way to partition your site into admin and public areas.

Answer (score 0):

Use [chown](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) to change the file/folder owner. In the php docs they say it works for files, but folders are just files and it should work. If it doesnt use [shell_exec](http://no.php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php) and use the OS chown (on *nix , donno about windows).

Alternatively you can use [HTTP authentication](http://php.net/manual/en/features.http-auth.php), if the folder is on a public path. I would not recommend .htaccess unless you are out of options. Htaccess were created for other reasons. Use the correct tools for each problem (see [Golden Hammmer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_the_instrument)).